# How to use angular -translate when the page reloads

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate

I am using angular-translate in my angular application.
I have set default language to German using

```
  $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('de')
```

I am also using `$translate.use(langKey)` which sets the languages at runtime.

But when i sets the language to `english` at runtime and then after that when i reload the page it sets the language again to `German`. what i want is that
After a refresh the page should be loaded in the language that it was set to before.

Is there something in angular which i can use or I have to write my own logic to implement the above.

Answer (score 2):

There are already some implementations for storing the chosen language built into angular-translate (via add-on modules). Have a look at https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/10_storages which provides built-in solutions for cookies and localstorage. Dealing with this manually is not that trivial as it looks at first sight.

With the module it is as easy as dropping in one javascript file and adding the following call when configuring the translate provider:

```
$translateProvider.useLocalStorage();
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use localstorage to keep the value in the cache, just inject the service $window in your controller and use this sintax:

```
$window.localStorage.setItem('lan', 'en');
```

the cache keep the value even after the browser is closed.
When you update the page just check if the key is present.

```
 if($window.localStorage.getItem('lan') === 'en'){
  //do something
 }
```

Local storage is bound to a specific domain,

You can see use the tab resources of the chrome web tools to check the existing key-value pairs

[image]

more info in the doc
https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage